# Tone.js - Note frequency

Tags: frequency, web-audio-api, tone.js

I'm writing a musical application using Tone.js library. I have a simple pad with notes which are played by the user.

I need to convert the "alphabetic" notation of a note (like A4,C3,D#4 ecc...) into frequencies.

I followed the documentation here: https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Frequency .

Based on the documentation i should be able to convert my note into frequencies simply with:

```
Tone.Frequency("C3")
```

I've been trying to use this line of code, but without any success.

If i try to run it in my browser console (obviously after importing the Tone.js library, which it's correctly included since my whole program works https://codepen.io/mattiasu96/pen/pxPXpB ), the command gives me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB1RQ.jpg
which doesn't seem a frequency at all.

What's the problem? Am i missing something? I can't figure out why i can't "extract" the frequency using the given command in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tone.Frequency()` is a constructor which creates an object which represents a frequency and provides various methods to convert that frequency. To get the actual frequency in Hertz you can use the [`toFrequency()`](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/Frequency#tofrequency) method.

```
Tone.Frequency('C3').toFrequency()
```

Comment: How to set frequency in hertz? Like in web audio api `oscillator.frequency.value = 440`. I dont want to be bound to specific note frequencies

Comment: It can also be created with values in Hertz as shown in the tests: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/blob/bfa600399fe15b8cbc5b2f19cb9c7043daf608b9/Tone/core/type/Frequency.test.ts#L112